# Append text to the end of the second line inline with memory concerns

Tags: bash, awk, sed, bioinformatics, text-editor

I am working with a file that looks sort of like this:

Hello.txt

```
mary had
a little
whose fleece was white as snow
```

I want it to look like this (asterisks for emphasis):

```
mary had
a little **lamb**
whose fleece was white as snow
```

The simple approach would be to vim into the file and add that word, but that's not possible. The third line is 3GB large in the actual case. It won't load properly.

Next, I tried to use sed:

```
sed -i '' '2s/$/ lamb/g' Hello.txt
```

Well, look at that, this works on the toy... but not for my actual case. When I run this on the honker of a file, I get:

```
sed: hg38.index: Cannot allocate memory
```

Notice that I am using the -i, it's because while I'm using Bash, I am on OSX.

I tried awk from [this SO question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29790/how-can-i-write-to-the-second-line-of-a-file-from-the-command-line). But it looks like Awk has no inline feature. Is there any way to do this without having to wait for the entire file to be loaded into memory? Thank you.

Comment: Is using a temporary file an option? If so, then `{ sed '2{s/$/ lamb/;q;}' file; tail -n +3 file; } > file.tmp` and `mv file.tmp file`.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin or: `mv -- file file.bak && sed '2{s/$/ lamb/;q;}' file.bak >file`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin I tried your method. Holy crap, it worked. Took ~15 minutes though.

Comment: GNU awk has an inline feature just like GNU sed and OSX/BSD sed have inline features but they all work the same way in that they make a copy of the input file and they'll all attempt to read that 3rd 3Gig line into memory so if one of them can't chances are none of them can.

Comment: It sounds to me like either you have a memory problem on your Mac or your version of sed is broken and not actually quitting after processing the 2nd line. How long does `{ head -n +2 Hello.txt; tail -n +3 Hello.txt; } > file.tmp` take? The version of that command with `sed` in place of `head` that M.NejatAydin proposed should take about the same length of time.

Comment: I had a thought on how that could take 15 mins - did you leave the `-i ''` in the command you ran so you actually ran `{ sed -i '' '2{s/$/ lamb/;q;}' file; tail -n +3 file; } > file.tmp`?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to do this in `ex`:

```
ex -sc '2s/$/ lamb/' -cx Hello.txt
```

Here is time comparison between `ex` and `sed` on my OSX for an input file of 200MB.

```
time ex -sc '2s/$/ lamb/' -cx big.txt

real    0m7.454s
user    0m6.519s
sys 0m0.831s


time sed -i '' '2s/$/ lamb/' big.txt

real    0m34.016s
user    0m32.913s
sys 0m0.722s
```

Here are timings for input file of 1.9GB:

```
time ex -sc '2s/$/ lamb/' -cx bigfile.txt

real    1m49.158s
user    1m16.310s
sys 0m19.578s


time sed -i '' '2s/$/ lamb/' bigf.txt

real    5m34.887s
user    5m25.308s
sys 0m6.197s
```

Comment: This doesn't work on my toy example... it hangs and I can't ctrl-C out of it. When I `man ex` I get the vim man page. Any idea?

Comment: It doesn't hang. It is processing your file. For ~2GB file it took ~2 min for me using `ex`

Comment: That's what I'm saying. I tried the code on the TOY example above. It made my console unresponsive.

Comment: I am also on OSX like you. Can you test `ex` command on a much smaller file first.

Comment: This is the third time I'm saying this. I tested it on Hello.txt FIRST. It hung.

Comment: ex is /usr/bin/ex is the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221233/discussion-between-anubhava-and-jeff).

Comment: Make sure you copy/paste `ex` command as is i.e. `ex -sc '2s/$/ lamb/' -cx Hello.txt`

Comment: Since the OP doesn't have enough memory for `sed` to read just the 3rd line into memory, it's unlikely they'll be able to read the whole input file into memory for `ex` to operate on it.

Comment: I suggested OP to first test `ex` on a small file and it seems OP tried on 3 liner file as well.

Comment: I was just saying, all else aside, in general it seems unlikely that this would work for the OP since it'll require `ex` to read more into memory than `sed` could fit in memory on their machine.

Comment: @anubhava OP has replied that tested with the sample file `Hello.txt` presented as a sample input in the question, which is already a very small file.

Comment: I am actually not clear on `it'll require ex to read more into memory than sed`. Why would `ex` read more in memory than `sed`?

Comment: sed reads 1 line at a time while ex reads the whole file at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ sed '2{s/$/ lamb/;q;}' Hello.txt; tail -n +3 Hello.txt; } > file.tmp
```

This is the solution that worked for me from M.NejatAydin. It took 15 minutes to run, but it worked. Checking head and tail -c, I can see the the first and last parts of the file are preserved, so I can only assume that the rest of the third line is fine.

It's ugly but from what I can tell, the first part prints the first two lines and appends text to the 2nd, and then the tail command outputs the rest of the file. Both are then piped to a tmp file. If anyone wants to clarify me, let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: The second line is correct. I can head it and check it that way. I can check the last 100 characters of the third line to see that what I put there is there correctly. I just can't check the middle of the third line. We should've done nothing to it.

Comment: Do it simply, if you are confused with the `{}`: `head -2 Hello.txt > temp.txt; sed -i '2s/$/ lamp/' temp.txt; tail -n +3 | cat temp.txt - > file.tmp`.